# how to use the datarange picker in rails there is any option is available for that

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

i am creating a simple application in rails in which i want a range of date to pick from user side so there any option available to do this i mean any gem  is available for that or can we this do with the help of the java script but i try to do this but it wouldn't work can any one have any suggestions for this 
can we create a customize datarange picker in html that would pick the date and we can use that value and use can also have the option to select options like last7 days and last month or something

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is option available in rails you can use the bootstrap daterange picker option for this rails also have gem for this caarlos0/bootstrap-daterangepicker-rails you can try this

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
  minDate: -20, 
  maxDate: "+1M +10D" 
  }
```

Also you can explore [this link](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)